# How to control the width of columns in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv, columns

I would like to use 3 or 4 columns (with variable width) in a `moderncv` document.

I think in the `vwcols` package, and with normal text, all works fine in the document, but when I try `vwcols` with lists in `moderncv`, I have trouble, and I can´t control the width.

What solution is suitable to control widths?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\firstname{\Huge{Manuel}}
\familyname{Dopazo Souto}
\title{\Large{Carpinteiro\newline{}\newline{}Wood worker}}
\address{Rúa dabaixo}{36.000, Pontevedra}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{649.45.74.35}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted                     % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%MICHI%\fax{fax (optional)}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{carpinteiro@carpinteiros.com}
\extrainfo{Data de nacemento: 2 de Xaneiro de 1.492}
\photo[60pt]{example-image-a.jpg}
\nopagenumbers{}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1.25cm, bottom=1.25cm,right=1.61cm, left=1.61cm}% inner=1cm, outer=0.618\textwidth
\vspace*{-0.56cm}
\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\vspace*{-1.24cm}
\vspace*{-0.18cm}

\section{Formación Académica}

\cventry{2015}{Carpinteria de arriba.}{}{}{\newline{}\scriptsize{Up's wood factory.}}{}{}{\scriptsize{Xan.}}

\cventry{2009--2014}{Carpinteria de abaixo}{}{}{\newline{}\scriptsize{Down wood factory. Galicia.}}{}{}{\scriptsize{Xaquin}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Habilitaciones por (valided by)\protect\includegraphics[width=1.4cm,valign=c]{example-image-b.jpg}}
%\cventry{Lista de cousas que sabe facer: (List of items)}{Sillas, banquetas, platos, chaveiros, portas, estantes, mobles,...}{}{}{\scriptsize{Galicia}}{}{}{}
\hspace*{\fill}
\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{How could I custom the with of cols?}
\begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
  \begin{multicols}{4}
    \textbf{Example 1}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Sample 1
      \item Sample 2
    \end{itemize}
    \columnbreak
    \textbf{Example 2}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Sample 3
      \item Sample 4
    \end{itemize}
    \columnbreak
    \textbf{Example 3}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Sample 5
      \item Sample 6
    \end{itemize}
    \columnbreak
    \textbf{Example 4}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Sample 7
      \item Sample 8
    \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2cm.}
\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{I think vwcols were an option but... I have no good results.}
\begin{minipage}%{\maincolumnwidth}
\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.26,0.37,0.37},
 sep=.8cm,justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=1em]
 % \begin{multicols}{4}
    \textbf{ESO}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Matemáticas
      \item Programación
      \item Robótica
      \item Informática
    \end{itemize}
    \newpage
    %\columnbreak
    \textbf{ESO}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Matemáticas aplicadas a las ciencias sociales.
      \item Matemáticas aplicadas a las enseñanzas académicas.
      \item Matemáticas aplicadas a las enseñanzas aplicadas.
      \item Métodos estadísticos y numéricos
    \end{itemize}
    \newpage
    %\columnbreak    
    \textbf{Bachillerato}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Matemáticas aplicadas a las ciencias sociales
      \item Métodos estadísticos y numéricos
      \item Robótica
      \item
    \end{itemize}
    \end{vwcol}
  %\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `moderncv` along with the modifications you want to make will take you more time (presumably). https://twitter.com/templateGundar/status/728103344015691776

Comment: @Johannes_B No, I have a solution. I don´t know about the cleverness/elegant of the sol but it works :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found one solution, use multiple minipages instead of vwcols. I don´t know if it´s clever/elegant but it works

[image]

```
\begin{itemize}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.14\linewidth}   
  \hfill
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
    \item Matemáticas
      \item Programación
      \item Robótica
      \item Informática
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\linewidth}
    \item Matemáticas aplicadas a las:
    \begin{itemize}
      \item ciencias sociales.
      \item enseñanzas académicas.
      \item enseñanzas aplicadas.      
    \end{itemize}      
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\linewidth}
      \item Métodos estadísticos y numéricos
      \item Robótica
      \item
  \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
```